# How to check picture of a Timage existence

Tags: delphi, image, exists, ram

I created 4 images, in which the character (game character, a car) looks at different directions, every time you press the arrow keys (up looks at up, down looks at down, left looks at left, right looks at right), here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
  var path,dleft,dright,dtop,dbot:string; 
begin
path:=paramstr(0);
dleft:=extractfilepath(path)+'Images\Pacman_Left.bmp';
dright:=extractfilepath(path)+'Images\Pacman_Right.bmp';
dtop:=extractfilepath(path)+'Images\Pacman_Top.bmp';
dbot:=extractfilepath(path)+'Images\Pacman_Bot.bmp';

  case Key of
     VK_UP:
    begin
      image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(dtop);
      image6.Top := image6.Top - 10;
      end;
     VK_DOWN:
       begin
       image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(dbot);
      image6.Top := image6.Top + 10;
      end;
    VK_LEFT:
       begin
       image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(dleft);
      image6.Left := image6.Left - 10;
      end;
    VK_RIGHT:
       begin
       image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(dright);
      image6.Left := image6.Left + 10;
  end;
  end;
end;
```

I think the code I am using is terrible, because if I press a key over than a time, it will reload the image and it will keep doing it as long as I keep pressing the same key, such a waste of RAM. What can I do about it?

Comment: It's many things, but not a waste of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvment: Load all images first (on application startup, say):

```
var
  bmCarLeft, bmCarRight, bmCarUp, bmCarDown: TBitmap;

...

bmCarLeft := TBitmap.Create;
bmCarLeft.LoadFromFile(dleft);
...
```

and then you can do

```
Image6.Picture.Assign(bmCarSomething)
```

every time you need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

There are really a lot of ways to do this.
Classic way:
One picture with all states of your item (car) and using Canvas.CopyRect() method to draw appropriate image from one to another;
Another way:
Load all your "sprites" to the TImageList and use TImageList.Draw() method.
And so on.
Main idea: use Canvas property of the destination picture and draw on it what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the way you manage images is best in the long run, but in the short term the simplest solution is to keep track of which image is currently loaded so you can load a new image only when actually needed, eg:

```
type
  eWhichImage = (imgUp, imgDown, imgLeft, imgRight);

const
  ImgFiles: array[eWhichImage] of string = (dtop, dbot, dleft, dright);

procedure TMyForm.ImageNeeded(const Img: eWhichImage);
begin
  if image6.Tag <> Ord(Img) then
  begin
    image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(ImgFiles[Img]);
    image6.Tag := Ord(Img);
  end;
end;
```

.

```
case Key of
  VK_UP:
  begin
    ImageNeeded(imgUp);
    image6.Top := image6.Top - 10;
  end;
  VK_DOWN:
  begin
    ImageNeeded(imgDown);
    image6.Top := image6.Top + 10;
  end;
  VK_LEFT:
  begin
    ImageNeeded(imgLeft);
    image6.Left := image6.Left - 10;
  end;
  VK_RIGHT:
  begin
    ImageNeeded(imgRight);
    image6.Left := image6.Left + 10;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In practice, you will not be able to declare the `ImgFiles` array, because `dtop` etc. aren't known at compile-time. Anyhow, I think the OP might consider combining this approach with my answer, since it isn't very satisfactory to load a file from disk every time you move the sprite.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: you can change `ImgFiles` into a non-const array and fill it in at program startup before you start processing user input.